# Потоки и общая очередь

Tags: потоки-данных, java

Пишу программу для обхода веб-графа в ширину.  
Входные параметры: набор исходных ссылок, глубина обхода, максимальное число загружаемых страниц. 
Во время загрузки каждой страницы из нее извлекаются ссылки на страницы.
По одной ссылке можно пройти только 1 раз. 
Программа должна завершать работы при достижении заданной глубины обхода или при достижении максимального числа загружаемых страниц.

Хочу реализовать программу так: создать 2 потока, каждому отдать на вход по половине исходных ссылок и запустить их. Дальше мне нужно получать от потоков информацию о том, сколько страниц они посетили и какие они ссылки при этом извлекли. Извлеченные ссылки хочу запихнуть в Set (это будет гарантировать то, что среди новых ссылок, по которым побегут потоки не будет одинаковых) и заново разделить этот сет на 2 части и раздать потокам.

Собственно вопрос: как мне получать информацию о количестве загруженных страниц и массив ссылок, которые удалось достать при посещении страниц?

**UPDATE**

```
    public static Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"([^\"#]+)\"");

public static String getContent(URL url) {
    StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder ();
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        String contentType = conn.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("text/html")) {
            if (contentType.indexOf("charset=") == -1) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            } else {
                String encoding = contentType.substring(contentType.indexOf("charset=") + 8);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), encoding));
            }
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                page.append(str);
            }
            in.close();
            return page.toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static Set<String> getLinks(URL url, String content) {
    Set<String> links = new HashSet<String>();
    Matcher matcher = linkPattern.matcher(content);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        try {
            URI link = new URI(new URL(url, matcher.group(1)).toString());
            links.add(link.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        }
    }
    return links;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Новый код в свете новой постановки задачи

```
private static class Element {
    public String url;
    public int onLvl;
    public Future<String> pageText;

    public Element(String u) {
        url = u;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return url.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (that == null || that.getClass() != Element.class)
            return false;
        return url.equals(((Element)that).url);
    }

}

private static List<Element> getAllUrlsFrom(String text, int lvl) {
    // здесь должен быть код достающий новые урлы
    // У всех возвращаемых Element уровень вложенности lvl + 1
    return new ArrayList<Element>(); 
}

private static class Downloader implements Callable<String> {

    private String url;

    public Downloader(String url) {
    // сюда же можно передавать сокет ли HttpClient для скачки 
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // код загрузки
        return null;
    }

}

/**
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int MAXLVL = 10;

    // 2 - кол-во соединений
    ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Queue<Element> queue = new LinkedList<Element>();
    Set<Element> explored = new HashSet<Element>();

    Element first = new Element("link");
    first.pageText = executer.submit(new Downloader(first.url)); 
    // или first.pageText = new Downloader(first.url).call() для синхронного вызова
    queue.add(first); // first

    while (queue.size() > 0) {

        Element el = queue.poll();

        if (explored.contains(el))
            continue;

        explored.add(el);

        if (el.onLvl == MAXLVL)
            continue;

        List<Element> childs = getAllUrlsFrom(el.pageText.get(), el.onLvl);

        for (Element c : childs) {
            if (!explored.contains(c)) {
                c.pageText = executer.submit(new Downloader(c.url));
                queue.add(c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @IronVbif предполагается загрузка контента(страниц) в потоках, результат загрузки должен отдаваться главному потоку, в котором достаются ссылки с тех страниц и запихиваются в очередь.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, а то не очень понимаю, что-то...
Вообщем Downloader разве не должен содержать метод run()?

Comment: @IronVbi, Кажется в классе Downloader не хватает поля URL url    
И еще - где и как лучше сделать повышение глубины у Element?     
В самом начале, при добавлении первой ссылки:
> queue.add(new Element("link"))

Неправильно так делать, т.к. у такого объекта класса Element pageText=null, что не правильно, т.к. дальше нам нужно это значение.    
Для этого отдельно вызываю метод для загрузки, но не получается конвертнуть String в Future<String> - как быть?

Comment: Удалил старые коменты и обновил ответ. Вам надо больше думать самому.

Comment: Код для загрузки требует контент страницы(типа String), а ему подается на вход переменная типа Future<String>, с которой ничего не могу сделать. Использовать toString() не приводит к результату     
Вот содержание контента, который должен поступать на вход методу, достающему ссылки:
> !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">> 
> icon"href="http://yandex.st/morda-logo/i/favicon.ico"><link 
> rel=alternate type="application/rss+xml"title="Новости Яндекса"

А на, если в переменной типа Future<String> применить toString(), то:
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@351563ff

Comment: В коде же написано el.pageText.get(). get() возвращает стринг. Что значит вы не можете конвертнуть?

Answer (score 4):

Делайте не так. Организуйте *очередь заданий*: множество ссылок, которые надо посетить, причём для каждой ссылки указана её глубина.

Очередь заданий будет всегда упорядочена по глубине.

Каждый поток делает следующее:

1. Берёт страницу из начала очереди заданий, удаляет её оттуда, помещает в список "отработанных заданий".
2. Скачивает страницу, если её глубина максимальна, возвращается к пункту 1.
3. Находит ссылки, выбрасывает те, которые уже в списке отработанных заданий.
4. Оставшиеся ссылки получают глубину на 1 большую, чем глубина их исходной страницы. Поток добавляет эти ссылки в очередь заданий так, чтобы не нарушить сортировку по глубине. То есть, если `n` -- глубина добавляемых ссылок, они добавляются после ссылок с глубиной `n-1` и перед ссылками с глубиной `n+1`. Если какая-то из ссылок уже есть в очереди и имеет меньшую глубину, новый экземпляр не добавляется. Если какая-то из ссылок уже есть в очереди и имеет большую глубину, она заменяется на новый экземпляр.
5. Возвращаемся к шагу 1, если заданий нет, ждём, пока они появятся; однако же если все потоки в ожидании, а заданий нет, алгоритм окончен.

Описанный алгоритм работает с любым количеством потоком, разумеется.

Comment: @VladD, 
> множество ссылок, которые надо посетить, причём для каждой ссылки
> указана её глубина.
У меня глубина одна для всех.    
    
А как мне из потоков формировать ту самую очередь? Было бы неплохо пример кода увидеть..

Comment: @Stas0n: не, я имел в виду текущую глубину, от корня.

Comment: @Stas0n: в качестве примера кода, посмотрите на [реализацию producer-consumer pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2332581/276994).