# Как найти все исходящие ссылки с сайта?

Tags: seo, ссылки

Кто-нибудь знает проверенный скрипт, или программу, которая сможет найти все исходящие ссылки с сайта и указать на каких страницах они расположены.

Будьте добры, поделитесь информацией.

Comment: `wget` + `grep/awk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204984/java-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C) есть мои 2 метода в описании топика, которые достают линки со страницы:
Вообщем-то, там ничего сложного - попробуйте..

Методы написаны на java

Comment: Решил вопрос программой Xenu's Link Sleuth

http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы была такая функция в программе Internet Download Manager

Answer (score 1):

Screaming Frog SEO Spider Tool [Страница инструмента](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) - считается одним из лучлих пауков для просмотра сайта. В т.ч. включает и список исходящих со страницами
Netpeak Spider [Страница инструмента](https://netpeaksoftware.com/spider) - аналог подешевле, тоже достаточно неплохой
Или другие SEO crawler'ы

https://ahrefs.com/ - сервис анализа доменов. Вводишь домен и выбираешь в группе Outgoing links - показывает какие ссылки на каких страницах